# jssor changing height depending on media queries

Tags: jssor

I want to change the height of my jssor slider depending on the viewport width, to ensure the HTML of my slide could be read. I'm using ScaleSlider function to scale the slider from desktop and tablet breakpoints, then when I'm in the mobile breakpoint (under 480px width) I want to change the size of the slider to be 100% width and another height (not proportional to initial width and height).

The only way to make it works is to reload the page (==re-initialize jssor)

CSS

```
.sliderContainer{
    width: 1180px;
    height: 680px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    @media screen and (max-width: $media-basicmobile-max){
        width: 300px;
        height: 425px;
    }
    .slides {
        width:1180px;
        height: 680px;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        @media screen and (max-width: $media-basicmobile-max){
            width: 300px;
            height: 425px;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Maybe cloning the slider HTML content and initializing the slider when window resizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a wrapper with breakpoints, and scale the slider to cover the whole wrapper area while window resizing. Please see the following example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Full Screen Slider Cover Window - Jssor Slider</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 1180px;
            height: 680px;
            max-width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            #wrapper {
                width: 300px;
                height: 425px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        jssor_slider1_init = function () {

            var options = {
                $SlideDuration: 800,                   //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $DragOrientation: 1,                   //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $AutoPlay: 1,                          //[Optional] Auto play or not, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to greater than 0. Default value is 0. 0: no auto play, 1: continuously, 2: stop at last slide, 4: stop on click, 8: stop on user navigation (by arrow/bullet/thumbnail/drag/arrow key navigation)
                $Idle: 1500                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            };

            var sliderContainerElement = document.getElementById("slider1_container");
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(sliderContainerElement, options);

            //#region responsive code begin
            //remove responsive code if you don't want the slider to scale along with window
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var wrapperElement = document.getElementById("wrapper");
                var wrapperWidth = wrapperElement.clientWidth;

                if (wrapperWidth) {
                    var wrapperHeight = wrapperElement.clientHeight;

                    var originalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();
                    var originalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

                    if (originalWidth / wrapperWidth > originalHeight / wrapperHeight) {
                        jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight(wrapperHeight);
                    }
                    else {
                        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(wrapperWidth);
                    }

                    //adjust vertical position
                    var scaleHeight = jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight();
                    sliderContainerElement.style.top = ((wrapperHeight - scaleHeight) / 2) + "px";
                }
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();

            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //#endregion responsive code end
        };
    </script>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -2500px; width: 5000px; text-align: center;">
            <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
            <!-- To move inline styles to css file/block, please specify a class name for each element. -->
            <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">

                <!-- Loading Screen -->
                <div data-u="loading" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background:url('../img/loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);"></div>

                <!-- Slides Container -->
                <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px;  height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;">
                    <div>
                        <img u=image src="../img/landscape/01.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u=image src="../img/landscape/02.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u=image src="../img/landscape/03.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u=image src="../img/landscape/04.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Trigger -->
                <script>
                    jssor_slider1_init();
                </script>
            </div>
            <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- remove the following if no need-->
    <p>other content</p>
</body>
</html>
```